# Javascript: Use switch statement to push an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement, javascript-objects

Here is a problem: Write a function that takes imageType and imageUrl and updates an object with fileName as key(value array) storing respective imageUrls on calling.

```
var attachmentLinks = {
  pdf: [],
  docx: [],
  png: [],
  jpg: [],
  xlsx: [],
  pptx: [],
  other: [],
};
var attachmentObj = {
  imgUrl: '',
  isDuplicate: false,
  duplicateCount: 0,
};
function addAttachmentToList(type, imgUrl) {
  let fileType = type.toLowerCase();
  this.attachmentObj['imgUrl'] = imgUrl;
  switch (fileType) {
    case 'pdf':
      this.attachmentLinks['pdf'].push(this.attachmentObj);
      break;
    case 'docx':
    case 'doc':
      this.attachmentLinks['docx'].push(this.attachmentObj);
      break;
    case 'png':
      this.attachmentLinks['png'].push(this.attachmentObj);
      break;
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'jfif':
      this.attachmentLinks['jpg'].push(this.attachmentObj);
      break;
    case 'xlsx':
    case 'csv':
      this.attachmentLinks['xlsx'].push(this.attachmentObj);
      break;
    case 'pptx':
      this.attachmentLinks['pptx'].push(this.attachmentObj);
      break;
    default:
      this.attachmentLinks['other'].push(this.attachmentObj);
      break;
  }
}
```

I am trying here to call function **addAttachmentToList**. The strange thing happening here is that  on calling the function more than one time it is updating all other keys in object *attachmentLinks* that previously recieved data, with the data recieved in last(latest) switch case.
AND if I am try to push any *string*(say imgUrl parameter)  instead of object(*attachmentObj*) in  the respective arrays in attachmentLinks it works fine. Can anyone help and explain why is this happening?

Comment: Please fix the format of your question. There's text in the code block. Don't use bold text for inline code. Wrap it in `\`` -> [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Try removing `this.` You should also avoid using square bracket notation for these properties. For example: `this.attachmentLinks['pdf'].push(this.attachmentObj);` should be `attachmentLinks.pdf.push(attachmentObj);`

Comment: @dj11223344 _"You should also avoid using square bracket notation for these properties"_ - Why? There's no reason to not use bracket notation.

Comment: @Andreas It's an anti-pattern. What purpose does bracket notation serve here? All the property names would be valid with dot notation and the code would look much cleaner.

Comment: @dj11223344 Please add a reference for that _"it's an anti-pattern"_ statement. _"What purpose..."_ - Maybe OP likes that version more than dot notation. _"would be valid with dot notation"_ - Sure, but that doesn't make it the only valid and working option. _"would look much cleaner"_ - That's your opinion. OP might think different.

Comment: @Andreas This has nothing to do with OPs question. There are several references in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets OP can do whatever they want. It's advice, not scripture. Clean code is important when working in a team environment.